# Explicit Example of Computing the Action

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, kinematics

I have been dealing with this problem for awhile and I have almost given up. I am asked to compute the action for a free particle going from $x = x_0 = 0$ at time $t = t_0=0$ to its end point $x = x_1 = v_0t_1$ at tie $t = t_1>0$.

The first part asks to compute the action, which I have done:
\begin{equation}
S = \int\frac{1}{2}mv^2dt = \frac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}\right)^2\int_0^{t_1} dt= \frac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}\right)^2t_1.
\end{equation}

The next part is asking, "suppose the particle has the $\textbf{same}$ initial and final points in space and time, but the initial velocity is $v_1\neq v_0$, so non-zero constant acceleration. The goal is to find $a$ as a function of $a(v_1)$, then give the trajectory of $x(t)$. (Note, $x(t)$ will not satisfy the equations of motion, which is a weird point as to why we are doing this if someone could explain why).

Ok, I have (maybe) done this part correctly since in general $x(t) = x_i + v_it + \frac{1}{2}at^2$. $\textbf{Here}$ is where things get weird for me, and I think somewhere in my work my indices are wrong, so to get $v_1$ out of $x(t)$, we need to go from $x_1\rightarrow x_2$ which gives,
\begin{equation}
x_2 = x_1 + v_1t_1 + \frac{1}{2}at_1^2\implies a(v_1) = \frac{2(x_2-x_1-v_1t_1)}{t_1^2}
\end{equation}
Then, if I plug this into the general $x(t)$ equation I find,
\begin{equation}
x(t) = x_0 + v_0t + \frac{(x_2 - x_1 - v_1t_1)t^2}{t_1^2}
\end{equation}

Note, I believe that I am wrong in my numbering of lower indices, and may or may not should assume the initial conditions and apply them. (This is because I have the $x_2$ term in there and I don't like it.

Finally, (and I think fixing the above will help with this one), the question asks to compute the action $I(v_1)$ for this trajectory, and then show that $dI/dv_1 = 0$. So, it will be the same action above, but compute the time derivative of part b, square it, and then plug into the action, compute the integral, then take the derivative. But I won't right out what I have for this as I believe my issue is part b.

I am really looking for a good hint, or starting point with part b, or simply what part b should be. I gave all my work, so the issue should (hopefully) be obvious. But of course, any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/728727/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic I posted that one... I just deleted the question since this one is more updated and precise.

Comment: @Qmechanic I now know I can use the initial conditions, BUT I can't find $a(v_1)$ without putting in $x_2$ since $x_1 = x_0 + v_0t_1 + \frac{1}{2}at_1^2$. But now see that $a\neq a(v_1)$.